# PowerShell arguments or Parameters

Tags: powershell

I have a script to rename computers on my network. I am trying to change it so that I can enter a current name and new name for the machine as an argument or parameter (which ever makes sense in this case.) Also I would like the script to check for the argument and if it does not exist import a CSV file.

This is what I came up with and it is not working. The param appear to be empty from the console output but the IF statement runs as if they are not.

```
param (
    $o = "oldname",
    $n = "newname"
)

if(!($o = $null)){
    if(!($n = $null)){
        Write-Host "Renaming computer from: $o to: $n"
        netdom renamecomputer $o /newName:$n /uD:domain\user /passwordD:* /force /reboot
    }
}else{
    Write-Host "Importing Computers from CSV file"
    $csvfile = "C:\Sysinternals\rename.csv"
    Import-Csv $csvfile | foreach { 
        $oldName = $_.OldName;
        $newName = $_.NewName;

        Write-Host "Renaming computer from: $oldName to: $newName"
        netdom renamecomputer $oldName /newName:$newName /uD:domain\username /passwordD:* /force /reboot
    }
}
```

Comment: This is very nearly an ideal case for the use of `[CmdletBinding()]` and `[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]` or `[Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true)]`. See [About_Functions_Advanced_Parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_parameters) for more information. (You can also get this information with `Get-Help about_Functions_Advanced_Parameters` in a Powershell console or the ISE.)

Comment: @JeffZeitlin His script is importing the new and the oldname from a csv in case the parameters are not specified. Why should he use the mandatory or valuefrompipeline attribute?

Comment: @MartinBrandl - Point taken. I'd actually end up rewriting this in one of two ways: (1) Two parameter sets - one for when I supply a computer name, and one when I want to import them from a file, or (2) ValueFromPipeline and then call it using `Import-CSV $csvfile | This-Script`. It ends up more flexible (I'm not locked to a particular CSV file name), and the code probably ends up easier to debug - to the extent that any debugging would be necessary in the first place.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin Agree, that would be a better function instead of magically doing it in the script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are **assigning** `$o` and `$n` to `$null` in your if statement - instead of *comparing* it. You can check whether `$o` is null like this:

```
if($o) 
{
}
```

But since you are comparing a string, you probably want to check whether the string is null or empty using the static `[string]::IsNullOrEmpty`method. So your refactored code could look like this:

```
param (
    $o = "oldname",
    $n = "newname"
)

if ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($o) -or [string]::IsNullOrEmpty($n))
{
    Write-Host "Importing Computers from CSV file"
    $csvfile = "C:\Sysinternals\rename.csv"
    Import-Csv $csvfile | foreach { 
        $oldName = $_.OldName;
        $newName = $_.NewName;

        Write-Host "Renaming computer from: $oldName to: $newName"
        netdom renamecomputer $oldName /newName:$newName /uD:domain\username /passwordD:* /force /reboot
    }
}
else
{
    Write-Host "Renaming computer from: $o to: $n"
    netdom renamecomputer $o /newName:$n /uD:domain\user /passwordD:* /force /reboot
}
```

Comment: if wanted to add the password as a parameter. would i just add a $password to the top of the param list?

Comment: sure you can do that.